# Testing ASP.NET Application from Attack

Tags: asp.net

I am building a Web Application in ASP.NET 4.0, using VS 2010 Professional.

I have tested the application against Sql injection, and user input.

Is there any other test necessary for me to do? Which tools should I use against external attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the [OWASP](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page) (Open Web Application Security Project) website - start with their [top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project).

Troy Hunt wrote a good blog series about the top 10 and how to mitigate against them and released it as [a free ebook](http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/12/free-ebook-owasp-top-10-for-net.html).

Answer (score 0):

[Burps Suite](http://portswigger.net/burp/) is the generally used penetration testing suite.  They offer a free version, but the paid version is fairly inexpensive (as far as these things go, it's $300.. many such tools cost over $1000)